# SQL compact synchronization

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I am synchronizing sql server and sqlCE database. once the synchronization is over, I need to delete the Sync Completed records from SqlCE database.(not from server). so that I can keep the db size low. When I delete the completed records and their trackings from SqlCE db, still there are "UploadChangesTotal" showing. How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

you can intercept the upload on the ChangesSelected event and remove the delete rows from the change dataset so they dont get propagated to the server.

see: [MANIPULATING THE CHANGE DATASET IN SYNC FX](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/)